# how to know is a view is the firts view loaded or not in ios

Tags: ios

is there a way to know if the view is first view in app after it get launched. to be more clear about it if in storybard i have a initial view controller set and in appdelegate

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
```

> ...some condition

```
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let initialViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "TabBarVC")
        self.window?.rootViewController = initialViewController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

what i want to know in the selected index viewcontroller if is comming from appdelegate or is come frome another view in the view hierarchy.

Comment: You can add property isInitial on your viewControllers and set ti to YES in the appDelegate before making it rootViewController.

Comment: well, you as the developer explicitly specify which one is first, why do you need to retrieve that information afterwards?

Comment: just thout that sdk have a way to handle this, what i want is to load a tableview controller with just a info from a push notification if comming from appdelgate or just load the table with data from api.